# How to use the callback plugin `log_plays` and keep `stdout` screen output simultaneously using `ansible-playbook`?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Adding the following in `ansible.cfg`:

```ini
stdout_callback = log_plays
callback_whitelist = log_plays
```

To enable the [`log_plays`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback/log_plays.html) callback plugin suppresses the standard screen output provided by running `ansible-playbook`.

Is there anyway to keep the `stdout` while taking advantage of the `log_plays` functionality?

I've tried just enabling the following in `ansible.cfg`

```ini
DEFAULT_VERBOSITY = 1
log_path = /var/log/ansible.log
```

but the log file isn't very clean.

Seeing if there's a "better" way to log a playbook?

Comment: As far as I know  you can only have one `stdout` type enabled at a time. Just a tip to improve log readability, you can try to use `stdout_callback = yaml` and enable the log through `log_path`.

Answer (score 0):

> ***How to use the callback plugin `log_plays` and keep `stdout` screen output simultaneously using `ansible-playbook`?***

Just by whitelisting it only.

With an `ansible.cfg`

```ini
[default]
stdout_callback         = yaml
callback_whitelist      = timer, profile_tasks, log_plays

[callback_log_plays]
log_folder              = /tmp/ansible/hosts
```

a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - debug:
```

will result into an `stdout` of

```yaml
PLAY [test] *********************************************************************************************
Saturday 14 October 2023  12:45:15 +0200 (0:00:00.041)       0:00:00.041 ******

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  msg: Hello world!

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************
test.example.com  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds
Saturday 14 October 2023  12:45:15 +0200 (0:00:00.068)       0:00:00.109 ******
===============================================================================
```

and a log file

```bash
~/test$ ll /tmp/ansible/hosts/
total 52
-rw-r--r--. 1 ansible_user users   314 Oct 14 12:45 test.example.com
```

with content

```bash
~/test$ cat /tmp/ansible/hosts/test.example.com
Oct 14 2023 12:45:15 - log_plays.yml -  - debug - OK - {"msg": "Hello world!", "changed": false, "_ansible_verbose_always": true, "_ansible_no_log": false}
```

**Further Q&A**

regarding the [`log_plays` callback](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/log_plays_callback.html) usage

- [Where is the host name derived from, for the name of the log file when using `log_plays` callback plugin in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77286744/6771046)

Answer (score 0):

For those who is looking for an up-to-date answer:

`callback_whitelist` was deprecated in favor of `callbacks_enabled`

So to have both: std output + file logs, you need to have in `ansible.cfg`:

```
[defaults]
callbacks_enabled = log_plays

[callback_log_plays]
log_folder = "/path/to/your/logs/folder"
```