# Where is the host name derived from, for the name of the log file when using 'log_plays' callback plugin in Ansible?

Tags: logging, ansible, ansible-inventory

I am using the `log_plays` plugin for logging in Ansible and have set the folder path for logging  in `ansible.cfg`

```ini
[callback_log_plays]
log_folder = /tmp/ansible/hosts
```

Log files are created with their names as the target host names but are sometimes in upper or lower case. I need to send a mail with the log file at the end of the play.

Where are these host names being read from and is there a way to change the name of the log file?

I want to know the name of the log file that is generated or change it to something else like the way the `log_folder` can be set.

Comment: The names are the one you define in your inventory. You can get al list of all hosts targeted by the play, not limited by the serial batch and including failed ones in `ansible_play_hosts_all`

Comment: Wild guess: Conflicts among dynamic inventory entries and [inventory cache](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/cache.html#enabling-inventory-cache-plugins)?

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there a way to change the name of the log file ... change it to something else like the way the `log_folder` can be set?*

According the documentation [`log_plays` callback – write playbook output to log file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/log_plays_callback.html), leading to [Ansible Galaxy - `community.general collection`](https://galaxy.ansible.com/ui/repo/published/community/general/) and finally the [Source Code of the Callback Plugin `log_plays.py`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/main/plugins/callback/log_plays.py#L86)

```py
path = os.path.join(self.log_folder, result._host.get_name())
```

it doesn't seems so out-of-box. Whereby the [`log_folder`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/environment_variables.html#envvar-ANSIBLE_LOG_FOLDER) is configurable, the filename is not.

But yes, it is possible in a Custom Callback Plugin version by adding some logic there. In example

```py
10 DOCUMENTATION = '''
...
20     options:
...
         hostname_prefix:
           default: PREFIX
           description: The string added before logging the inventory_hostname.
           env:
             - name: ANSIBLE_HOSTNAME_PREFIX
           ini:
             - section: callback_log_plays
               key: hostname_prefix
'''
...
68      self.hostname_prefix = self.get_option("hostname_prefix")
86      path = os.path.join(self.log_folder, self.hostname_prefix + '-' + result._host.get_name())
```

```ini
[callback_log_plays]
log_folder              = /tmp/ansible/hosts
hostname_prefix         = TEST
```

ending up with logs such as

```bash
~/test$ ll /tmp/ansible/hosts/
total 12
-rw-r--r--. 1 ansible_user users 157 Oct 13 12:15 test.example.com
-rw-r--r--. 1 ansible_user users 157 Oct 13 12:15 localhost
-rw-r--r--. 1 ansible_user users 157 Oct 13 12:20 PREFIX-test.example.com
-rw-r--r--. 1 ansible_user users 157 Oct 13 12:25 TEST-test.example.com
```

It introduces an additional Custom Configuration Setting and utilize it. As one can see, a prefix and a delimiter which will be added before the `inventory_hostname`.

---

> *Log files are created with their names as the target host names but are sometimes in upper or lower case.*

If one just want to do some [Data Cleansing](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/111804/52286) it is possible to tweak the plugin with only

```py
path = os.path.join(self.log_folder, result._host.get_name().lower())
```