# Ansible remote log to custom location per managed node

Tags: ansible

While reading the [ansible doc about logging](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/logging.html) I found the following text:

> Logging Ansible output By default, Ansible sends output about plays,
> tasks, and module arguments to your screen (STDOUT) on the control
> node. If you want to capture Ansible output in a log, you have three
> options:
>
> To save Ansible output in a single log on the control node, set the
> log_path configuration file setting. You may also want to set
> display_args_to_stdout, which helps to differentiate similar tasks by
> including variable values in the Ansible output.
>
> **To save Ansible output in separate logs, one on each managed node, set**
> **the no_target_syslog and syslog_facility configuration file settings.**
>
> To save Ansible output to a secure database, use AWX or Red Hat
> Ansible Automation Platform. You can then review history based on
> hosts, projects, and particular inventories over time, using graphs
> and/or a REST API.

Is it also possible to log on the managed node to a custom location?
On each host I want to log to /log/[machine_name].log

Where machine_name is the name of the machine.

context: log is a mount point so will be possible to access from all machines, that is the reason I want to have different names for the log files.

Question that might help help finding the answer, is 'log_path' used for the managed nodes and the control node? or is it only used for the control node?

Comment: Not a full answer yet, but some information you'll find in [Where is the hostname derived from, for the name of the log file when using `log_plays` Callback Plugin in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77286744/6771046).